# Scalatest Error When Using FlatSpec

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I ran my test, which failed, but for the following (seemingly-contradictory) reason:

```
should return an myClassVector *** FAILED ***
[info]   Expected myClassVector(3, 9, 12), but got myClassVector(3, 9, 12)
```

Here is my actual test:

```
 class myClassVector extends FlatSpec
{
     "myClassVector" should "return myClassVector" in {
            val test = Vector[Int](1, 3, 4)
            val cvec = new myClassVector(test)

            assertResult(cvec(3,9,12)){cvec * 3}
                                                                                           }

}
```

I would like to also note that:

```
assertResult((3,9,12)){cvec*3}
```

doesn't work either.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the class that you are testing (`myClassVector`) was declared as a `case class` then the compiler automatically created a `equals` method on your class that does a comparison of the fields in your class to test for equality.  But if you declared `myClassVector` as a vanilla class (without the `case` keyword) then you will need to provide your own `equals` method.

Here is an example:

```
class myClassVector(val a: Int, val b: Int, val c: Int) {
  override def equals (that: Any) = that match {
    case that: myClassVector =>
      a == that.a && b == that.b && c == that.c
  }
}
```

Cheers!